# Como tratar o erro QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate;

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

O id é auto increment, mas o id_uc é unique, justamente para não entrar um id_uc igual. quero que retorne para view uma mensagem.

```
$storm =new ListaStorm();
$storm->id = $id;
$storm->id_uc = $id_uc;
$storm->save();
```

mensagem de erro?

```
@foreach($storm as $s)
{{$s->id}} 
{{$s->id_uc }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: porque não faz a validação ??? se não implementou a classe RequestForm?

Comment: não sei fazer validação desse tipo ; (

Comment: Você pelo menos tem o controller a View ? para que a resposta seja baseada nisso?

Comment: o controller tem a view sim!

Comment: Então poste na sua pergunta tanto o controller tanto a View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Precisa configurar a sua aplicação para que na hora da requisição seja feita a validação do seu modelo, um exemplo minimo com validação:*

***O Model***

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ListaStorm extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'listastorm';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['id_uc'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

***A classe de validação***

*Na classe de validação é colocado duas validações essenciais: `required` isso significa que o dado é obrigatório e `unique` com o paramentro do nome da tabela, significa que esse dados não pode repetir:*

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ListaStormRequest extends FormRequest
{    
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return ['id_uc' => 'required|unique:listastorm'];
    }
}
```

***O Controller***

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ListaStormRequest;
use App\ListaStorm;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ListaStormController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('lista', ['items' => ListaStorm::all()]);
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }
    public function store(ListaStormRequest $request)
    {
        ListaStorm::create($request->only('id_uc'));
        return redirect(route('lista.index'));
    }
}
```

***com as devidas rotas que no caso exemplo são 3:***

```
Route::get('lista',['as'=>'lista.index','uses'=>'ListaStormController@index']);
Route::get('lista/create',['as'=>'lista.create','uses'=>'ListaStormController@create']);
Route::post('lista/store',['as'=>'lista.store','uses'=>'ListaStormController@store']);
```

***a suas Views:***

- **index.blade.php**

  ```
  @extends('layouts.app')

  @section('content')
      <div>
          @foreach($items as $item)
            <p> {{$item->id}} . {{$item->id_uc}} </p>
          @endforeach
      </div>
  @endsection
  ```
- **create.blade.php**

  ```
  @extends('layouts.app')

  @section('content')
  @if ($errors->any())
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
           <ul>
              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                   <li>{{ $error }}</li>
              @endforeach
           </ul>
      </div>
  @endif
  <div>
      <form action="{{route('lista.store')}}" method="post">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <input type="text" id="id_uc" name="id_uc">
          <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
      </form>
  </div>
  @endsection
  ```

No momento de submete o formulário se o dados já existir ele retorna na View Create e mostra a mensagem:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como é pretendido pelos dados da pergunta.

***Referencias:***

- [Laravel - Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)
- [Laravel - Validation [rule-unique]](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique)
- [Laravel - Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation)

Answer (score -1):

Eu faria assim

```
$request->validate(['id_uc' => 'unique:listastorm,id_uc']);
```